How to resolve SSL error [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_RECORD_MAC] ssl/tls alert bad record mac when pushing data to Supabase using httpx in Python?
I'm encountering an SSL error while pushing data to Supabase using the httpx library in Python. The error message is [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_RECORD_MAC] ssl/tls alert bad record mac (_ssl.c:2580). This issue occurs intermittently, usually after successfully pushing several batches of data.
Here is the relevant part of my code:
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import supabase

class DataProcessor:
    def __init__(self, push_url, push_key, df):
        self.push_url = push_url
        self.push_key = push_key
        self.df = df

    def process_data(self):
        supabase_push = supabase.create_client(self.push_url, self.push_key)
        df = self.df.replace({pd.NA: None, np.nan: None})
        
        for i in range(0, len(df), 25000):
            try:
                data = df[i:i + 25000].to_dict(orient='records')
                
                # Check for duplicate IDs and index
                if len(df[i:i + 25000]['id'].unique()) != len(df[i:i + 25000]):
                    print('Duplicate IDs at index:', i)
                    break
                if len(df[i:i + 25000].index.unique()) != len(df[i:i + 25000]):
                    print('Duplicate Index at index:', i)
                    break

                data = supabase_push.table('budget_table').upsert(data).execute()
                print('Pushed', i + 25000, 'rows')
            
            except:
                print('Retrying')
                time.sleep(20)
                supabase_push = supabase.create_client(self.push_url, self.push_key)
                data = df[i:i + 25000].to_dict(orient='records')
                data = supabase_push.table('budget_table').upsert(data).execute()
                print('Pushed', i + 25000, 'rows')
df = pd.read_csv('feb_24.csv')
processor = DataProcessor('dev_url', 'dev_key', df, 0)
processor.process_data()

The error trace is as follows:
Retrying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/httpcore/_sync/http11.py", line 224, in _receive_event
    data = self._network_stream.read()
  File "/path/to/httpcore/_backends/sync.py", line 124, in read
    with map_exceptions(exc_map):
  File "/path/to/contextlib.py", line 158, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/path/to/httpcore/_exceptions.py", line 14, in map_exceptions
    raise to_exc(exc) from exc
httpcore.ReadError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_RECORD_MAC] ssl/tls alert bad record mac (_ssl.c:2580)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/supabase/main.py", line 203, in process_data
    data = supabase_push.table('event_pitching_v2').upsert(data).execute()
  File "/path/to/httpx/_client.py", line 1015, in _send_single_request
    response = transport.handle_request(request)
  File "/path/to/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 86, in map_httpcore_exceptions
    raise mapped_exc(message) from exc
httpx.ReadError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_RECORD_MAC] ssl/tls alert bad record mac (_ssl.c:2580)

Steps I've already tried:
• Updated all related libraries (httpx, httpcore, etc.) to the latest versions.
• Made sure the ID and Index were both unique.
It will sometimes upload batches of rows but is getting stuck on something. I apologize for my ignorance of working with cloud databases.

The error is at the other end. Nothing you can do except exert pressure on them to get it fixed.
